# Смена формата отображения DateTime в DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

Делаю вот такую штуку

```
<DataGrid ...>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        ...
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Дата"
                            Binding="{Binding date, StringFormat=dd/MM/yyyy}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Можно ли как то сюда `StringFormat=dd/MM/yyyy` подгружать формат из другого источника автоматически, то есть не явно прописывать его, а сделать источник с форматами.

Comment: Не проще конвертер тогда написать и форматировать тогда дату как душе угодно?

Comment: @tym32167 Да вот как бы пример увидеть такого конвертера, и его же вызывать надо по событию?

Comment: А что особенного в таком конвертере и при чем тут события? Наверное, вам имеет смысл расписать вашу задачу подробнее

Comment: @tym32167 я наверное не так выразился про события

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как верно заметили в комментариях, вашу задачу можно решить с помощью *мульти*конвертера.

У меня есть такая база для конвертера:

```
abstract class MultiConverterBase : MarkupExtension, IMultiValueConverter
{
    public abstract object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture);
    public virtual object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => this;
}
```

Дописываем:

```
class DateFormatConverter : MultiConverterBase
{
    public override object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var date = (DateTime)values[0];
        var format = (string)values[1];
        return date.ToString(format);
    }
}
```

Теперь всё просто, если у меня есть такая VM:

```
class MainVm : Vm
{
    public List<Item> Items { get; } = new List<Item>
    {
        new Item(DateTime.Today, "dd/MM/yyyy"),
        new Item(DateTime.Today, "yyyy-MM-dd"),
        new Item(DateTime.Today, "d.MM.yy"),
        new Item(DateTime.Today, "D"),
    };
}

class Item
{
    public DateTime Date { get; }
    public string Format { get; }

    public Item(DateTime date, string format)
        => (Date, Format) = (date, format);
}
```

Я могу вот так к ней привязаться:

```
<ItemsControl xmlns:c="clr-namespace:WpfTest" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{c:DateFormatConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="Date"/>
                        <Binding Path="Format"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Если вы хотите менять формат "на лету", просто реализуйте `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, отличный пример ,а еще вопрос вы используете viewmodel а если вопрос просто чистого wpf  ,без mvvm, Такое возможно?

Comment: Если вы реализуете INotifyPropertyChanged в классе Item, то всё будет работать так же, MVVM тут особо не причем, это штатная система привязок WPF

Comment: Ок спасибо большое